# What is the best method of computing $a^{(k)}/k!$?

Tags: accuracy

I have the following expression
$$
\frac{a^{(k)}}{k!}
$$
where $a^{(k)}$ is the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Properties). Is it better to evaluate it using floating-point arithmetic separately, that is, call a function that returns the numerator and another function that returns the denominator, and then divide? Or should I evaluate it by expanding
$$
\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{a+i-1}{i}
$$
I tend to think that the second method is more stable because factorials can quickly grow really big, which may lead to a loss of accuracy. But I have never really checked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the programming environment provides an implementation of the beta function $\mathrm{B}(x,y)$ this computation is straightforward and usually accurate. We have

$$x^{(k)} = \frac{\Gamma(x+k)}{\Gamma(x)}, \ \ \ \ \ k!=\Gamma(k+1), \ \ \ \ \  \mathrm{B}(x,k)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(x+k)}$$

Thus

$$f(x,k) = \frac{x^{(k)}}{k!} = \frac{\Gamma(x+k)}{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(k+1)}=\frac{\Gamma(x+k)}{k\Gamma(x)\Gamma(k)}=\frac{1}{k\mathrm{B}(x,k)}$$

For example $f(9,7) = 6435$. Examples of programming environments that provide the beta function are ISO C++17 or later, Julia, and the SciPy and Boost libraries. Best I can tell from a quick perusal, the beta function is not part of ISO Fortran 2018, but it is *presumably* available via the NAG and IMSL libraries.

Note the use of the weasel words "usually accurate" above. According to some quick ad-hoc tests some beta function implementations exhibit a maximum error on the order of 100 ulps. The likely cause of this is that they compute $\ln (\mathrm{B}(x,y))$ fully accurate to double precision and then simply exponentiate this intermediate result, thereby suffering from the error magnification property of $\exp$. One way around this is to compute $\ln (\mathrm{B}(x,y))$ with extended precision; for double-precision computation twelve additional bits would suffice to compute $\mathrm{B}(x,y)$ with a maximum error of a few ulps. This is not an unusual issue: similar scenarios occur in implementations of `tgamma()` and `pow()` from the C++ standard math library, for example.

Comment: When $k=0$, $f(x,k) = 1$. So, $B(x,k)$ goes to infinity when $k=0$?

Comment: @nougako $\mathrm{B}(x,k)$ goes to $\infty$ when $k=0$. If you allow $k=0$, you will need to special case that to avoid producing a NaN when using IEEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 8):

Njuffa already answered satisfactorily, but let me comment that dealing with large numbers does not cause loss of precision in floating-point arithmetic: the error is a *relative* one, corresponding to a multiplicative term: the result of $ab$ is approximated with $ab(1+\varepsilon)$, with $|\varepsilon|$ smaller than machine precision, independently of the size of $a$ and $b$.

Computing numerator and denominator separately is a bad idea because of a different issue, that of overflow: after $a$ or $k$ are larger than something around 30, numerator and/or denominator become larger than the largest floating point number, which is about $10^{308}$ for `float64` / `double`, and the computation fails. But if overflow does not happen, then the relative error is always bounded by $1+3k\mathsf{u} + O(\mathsf{u}^2)$ (that is, $\mathsf{u}$ for each operation).